# GRAPH API Cannot filter enum

Tags: enums, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to filter SSPR results from AAD directoryAudits using:-
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits?filter=category eq 'SSPR'
This works fine, however if I try to filter on say the result:
result eq success
"result": "success"
I get the error:-
"message": "The string 'Microsoft.AAD.Reporting.operationResult'success'' is not a valid enumeration type constant.",
So I have searched in the metadata and found some appropriate enums, and tried them, but nothing seems to work!
This seems such a simple thing, but I can't seem to work out a way past it.
I'm not sure if it is just this field, or enums in general.
Please help :)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So what I am trying to do (this is from postman):-

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits?top=10&filter=(category eq 'SSPR') and (activityDisplayName eq 'Unlock user account (self-service)' and result eq 'success')
But I cannot seem to filter on result. 
Example JSON I get is:-
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#auditLogs/directoryAudits",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "SSPR_xxx",
            "category": "Self-service Password Management",
            "result": "success",

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `the string 'Microsoft.AAD.Reporting.operationResult'success'' is not a valid enumeration type constant`, it means that $filter `success` is **not supported**.

Per [List directoryAudits](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/directoryaudit_list) API, the following attributes are supported by $filter.
But based on my test and you mentioned that `category` also is supported.

[image]

If possible, you could filter the `result` on the client as workaround.